# Layman's Terms on a MAX IF MOD COLUMN function [EXCEL]

Tags: excel-formula

I was told a function that searches every Nth column and returns the max value.

```
=MAX(IF(MOD(COLUMN(C4:FB4),3)=1,C4:FB4))
```

Can someone explain this please?

What I really fail to understand is:

- what the `=1` does
- If I change it to `=2`, why does it pull from the next column

Answer (score 0):

The MOD() function returns the remainder of the division.

So `=MOD(10,3)` would return 1 because 10/3 = 3 with a remainder of 1.

In this case it is taking the column number and dividing it by 3 and seeing what the remainder is.

So it would look at any column that issues that remainder, like Column D which is column 4 and 4/3 = 1 with a remainder of 1.  Column E would return a remainder of 2.